# Confused with return type of Method

Tags: java, methods, return-value

Anyone please explain why we return value at first place.
I mean value returned by method changes instance variable ? or it will change  copy of instance variable accessed by objects ?

Any good links which will help me to understand purpose of returning value from method ?

I have two classes :

**Phone.java**

```
class Phone{
    double weight; //instance variable

    void setWeight(double val) { // method talking double value but not returning
        weight = val;
    }
    double getWeight(){ //method returning double value
         return weight;
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String args [] ) {

    Phone phone = new Phone();


    double newWeight = p.getWeight();
    double newWeight3 = p.setWeight;

    int newWeight2 = p.getWeight();
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- Method `setWeight` talking ***double val*** in it's parameter but not returning value so no changes are made into instance variable weight in class phone.. right ?
- Method `getWeight` is returning value to weight but we are not passing any argunments into method getWeight!!
- What changes need to made in either of these method so that we can assign by returning value ?

Answer (score 1):

We pass value to `setter` methods because they need some value to be set to some other field (usually a field in the class). We are not expecting anything to be returned. The method is only meant to set the value.

We don't pass a value to getters because we know the instance on which the getter is being called and hence know what value to fetch. Since we need some return value, we return the value.

Answer (score 0):

It's called encapsulation, we do it so that only the class can modify the variable.

The other option would have been to make weight public, it which case we would not need getters and setters, but then the class does not have control over its own members and behaviour.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: ok, thanks you sir for reply
i will read this method return type and encapsulation section one more type :)

Comment: I don;t think the OPs question is about *encapsulation*. I believe it is very very basic :)

Comment: Oh, maybe I'm reading to much into the question :)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, we can set the weight of `Phone phone` like this:

```
phone.setWeight(32.12)//or whatever value you want to pass
```

If we want to retrieve the value of `phone` we can do this:

```
double tmp = phone.getWeight();
```

We can then do what we want with tmp like any variable.

Notice how with `setWeight` we do not assign it to any variable. That is because it has a return type of void.

Notice, in the second value we do not pass anything into the `getWeight()` method parameters. This is because it takes no arguments. Because it returns a value, we can set a variable (tmp) to have that value.